# How can I automatically stop putty disconnecting

Tags: ssh, putty

Unless I set "Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off)" to 2 putty keeps disconnecting after a few minutes of inactivity. How can I fix this once and for all? I can't find where putty settings are stored on my PC

Comment: why not check "Enable TCP keepalives" ?

Comment: I can do that but it doesn't save. Every time I open putty I need to set that. How can I set it permanently?

Comment: Change it and save in default profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putty settings can only be saved if assigned to a saved session.

The process is usually to configure putty as you like, go back to the first Category ("session"), enter a name, and click "Save" to save your settings.

If you don't want to have to load the session each time,you have to save the session as "Default Settings" in the saved sessions list.

Answer (score 2):

If you have trouble saving this on the client site for some reason, you could consider setting it on the server side (assuming you have root access there) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

Comment: Could you please tell is it same to setting `ServerKeepAlive <sec>` in client conf file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` ?

Comment: @heemayl I am not sure if `putty` reads that. I know that `ssh` does and for the ssh-client you can set that in that file.

Comment: Actually i have referred to `openssh-client` ..just curious..so i can set any one? either in server or client?

Comment: For the ssh client you can set it there, or in `~/.ssh/config` for the client and like I indicated in my answer for the server